# Identifying two distributions from a circular scan and then finding their centre points

Tags: clustering, circular-statistics

I’ve got three clusters of points. These are 315 readings taken from a circular scan, i.e. the reading at x = 315 is actually next to x =0.

There are two clusters in the data - zero and non-zero (but the readings have an element of noise (gaussian).

I’ve plotted a moving average to be able to visualise this. I’m trying to return the mid point (in terms of x) of the non-zero group (i.e. approx x = 190).

[image: moving average plot]

I tried k-means clustering, with the intent of taking the centre point of the non-zero cluster, this gives 195 but is affected by outliers.

[image: k means plot]

This seems a bit of a hack. Grateful for any ideas on better ways of doing this.

I originally asked the question here [orig stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49068022/using-k-means-clustering-to-cluster-based-on-single-variable), but it was suggested that this community may be more appropriate.

Comment: Welcome to our site!  Your last plot is confusing because it suggests you are clustering on the y-coordinate, whereas the question concerns clustering on the x-coordinate.  Have you considered representing your data in more than one dimension at a time?  Try clustering (using any method) based on $(\cos(\omega x),\sin(\omega x),\lambda y)$ where $\omega=2\pi/315$ and $\lambda$ is a suitably chosen scale factor.  Your graphs suggest that almost any method (K-means, SVM, etc) will perform extremely well on that.

Comment: Thanks, will look into those. I am clustering on y. The issue is trying to return the mid point of the higher cluster in terms of x

Comment: Please do not cross-Post duplicates! https://stackoverflow.com/q/49068022/1060350